# Boot Xubuntu from USB not working

Tags: xubuntu

I downloaded xubuntu to my flash drive but when i connect it to my eee pc 900 it didn't work even though it is the 1st device in the boot. can you help me

Comment: I would verify the media & xubuntu on your install (using another system is easier than my own eeepc 1000), then ensure your eeepc boots a thumb-drive.  From experience I know booting flash drives can be problematic on old eeepc, and installation from dvd/cdr is usually easiest (using usb-dvd/cd-drive); I can't recall the reason why it was difficult on eepc's but I suspect it's the bios.

Comment: what should I do, btw I installed xubuntu bionic beaver

Comment: I help QA-test (quality assurance) Lubuntu & Xubuntu, and planned using two eeepcs in that role, but found the device a pain & dropped it preferring older thinkpads & latitudes, as I didn't want to mess with cdr/dvdr but use thumb-drives. Maybe the two I had were just a pain, but it's why I suggested validating the thumb-drive on another machine etc. in prior comment.

Comment: thanks i just installed the xubuntu and i am just waiting for it